# How export old C dll for use in C# Class Library

Tags: c++, c, dll, export, console-application

There are two **old C** files with tow related **headers**.
For use them in Visual Studio 2013 i created a `Visual C++ Win32 Console Application` and disabled precompiled headers from properties of project.
I deleted `stdafx.h` & `targetver.h` & `dllmain.cpp` && `project_name.cpp(created by vs)`.
in `Header Files` area i added two files And in `Source Files` area i added another tow files.
My project is look like this :

[[image: my project]]

[Here is my entire project's link](http://www.rodfile.com/alaeux6ozhbw)

Consider on `.c` file extensions(no `.cpp`).
In header files there is no `class` usage and you will see many `structs` in there because of old c language.
Now i want to export this project's dll for use in a simple console application `c#` project.
How can do that?
I put this peace of code in the upper of both header files :

```
__declspec(dllexport) int main();
```

`int main()` function is inside `wmm_file.c` file and this main function uses many functions in another c file (`GeomagnetismLibrary.c`).
I want to use all functions of c++ project in c# code.
Here is my c# codes (`Prpogram.cs`) :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Magnetic_Model_CSharp

        [DllImport(@"Y:\Magnetic_Model_C_dll_2.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern int main();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            main();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the error after run :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException'
>   occurred in Magnetic_Model_CSharp.exe

How can i fix this error and make that c(c++) project exportable?

**Edit :**
As my friends said you shouldn't use main keyword so i renamed it.
For a test i created a simple
**Declaration :**

```
int Add(int a, int b); /* PUT IT ON GeomagnetismHeader.h FILE*/
```

**Definition :**

```
int Add(int a, int b) /* PUT IT ON wmm_file.c FILE > I RENAMED main() TO main_____() IN THIS FILE*/
{
    printf("Hello Joy!\r\n");
    return a + b;
}
```

And renamed both

```
__declspec(dllexport) int main();
```

To

```
__declspec(dllexport)
```

In both header files.
Now the problem is the position of declaration of `int Add(int a, int b);` function in `GeomagnetismHeader.h` file.
When i put it before **typedef struct {** it works.
But when i put it after **typedef struct {** does not work and all of my declarations are after **typedef struct {**.
Any idea?

Comment: With this tutorial we can export c++ dll (oop) with keyword of class, But what about this situation? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx

Comment: You should not name a function `main` in that DLL.